# Set custom view in main window in Swift on OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I have create a new class with NSView as the base class, I then want to see it in the main window of my app. In the AppDelegate class, I have access to a NSWindow object, I was guessing I could use setContentView() with my custom view, but weirdly that function is not defined even though [it's in the documentation of NSWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

I'm kind of a noob when it comes to coding on UI stuff OSX, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your custom NSView as a subview

self.window.contentView.addSubview(YOURCUSTOMNSVIEW)